# How to split a string into Left sub-string and Right sub-string with delimiter as Unicode

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, unicode

I have a string with Unicode. I want to split the string into the left sub-string and right sub-string with Unicode as a delimiter.

For example, a given string is:

```
str = 'Oh wow. Magnificent! Ariadna Garcia! <U+2764> <U+2764> wonderful'
```

I want output as:

```
leftstr = 'Oh wow. Magnificent! Ariadna Garcia!'

uni_code = '<U+2764> <U+2764>'

rightstr = 'wonderful'
```

I thought of using regex to identify the Unicode and then find an index of Unicode using find(). Then use string slicing and cutting approach with indices, that is, leftstr = starting index to one less than the index of unicode. Then, rightstr = (starting index of Unicode+length of Unicode) till end of the string.
The problem is that my regular expression to identify Unicode is not working. I feel, my approach is complex. Is there any elegant way to get desired substrings as output.

The following code, I have tried so far:

```
import re str1 = 'Oh wow. Magnificent! Ariadna Garcia! <U+2764> wonderful'
pattern = r'<U\+.*?>' 
indx = str1.find(pattern) 
print(indx)
```

The regular expression is not working as desired.

Comment: Do you *literally* have the characters `<U+2764>` (length 8) in your string? or is that a placeholder for the *actual* Unicode character U+2764 (❤)?

Comment: Yes, I do have Unicode U+2764 (❤) in my string.

Comment: Every character in your string is a Unicode character, so you’ll have to be more specific about what you want. U+004F is `O` for example.

Comment: Ok! I am concerned with emoji Unicode only.

Answer (score 0):

There are unfortunately many emoji, and many of those are multiple sequences, so a generic solution is complicated.  Here's Unicode's complete list:

https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-13.0/emoji-list.html

A direct solution is:

```
import re

s = 'Oh wow. Magnificent! Ariadna Garcia! ❤ ❤ wonderful'
left,emoji,right = re.split(r'(\u2764 \u2764)',s)
print(left,emoji,right,sep='\n')
```

```
Oh wow. Magnificent! Ariadna Garcia! 
❤ ❤
 wonderful
```

You could parse these [Unicode data files](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/) to create more complex regular expressions.  For example, this parses a range of emoticons:

```
import re

s = 'OneTwoThreeFourFive'
result = re.split(r'([\U0001F600-\U0001F64F])',s)
print(result)
```

```
['One', '', 'Two', '', 'Three', '', 'Four', '', 'Five']
```

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I have different emoji Unicode in the text and I need a left string to every Emoji Unicode and their right string as well. For your second example, I want the output as- leftstr1=One Emoji1= rightstr1=Two; leftstr2=Two Emoji2= rightstr2=Three; leftstr3=three Emoji3= rightstr3=Four; leftstr4=Four Emoji3= rightstr4=Five. Of course, we will use lists. I am currently facing problem in splitting string as desired.